# Xml Text Edit in C#

Tags: c#

i have some trouble to edit an file.

i tried to scan for " Module Name="+0.1.2HUB" Type="0AC808.9" " in an long XML
if the text is found i would like to insert an text the next line.

if not write this:

```
<Module Name="+0.1.2HUB" Type="0AC808.9" Frozen="true" LastFrozenVersion="1.0.0.0" Version="1.0.0.0">
 <Connection Connector="ETH1" TargetModule="+0.1.2HUB" TargetConnector="PLK1" />
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
 <Connection Connector="ETH8" TargetModule="80274418TLS03" TargetConnector="IF3">
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
</Module>
```

The string to be inset loos like this:

```
 <Connection Connector="ETH2" TargetModule="+0.1.2HUB" TargetConnector="PLK1" />
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
```

The optimal result would be this if the scanresult is True:

```
<Module Name="+0.1.2HUB" Type="0AC808.9" Frozen="true" LastFrozenVersion="1.0.0.0" Version="1.0.0.0">
 <Connection Connector="ETH1" TargetModule="+0.1.2HUB" TargetConnector="PLK1" />
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
 <Connection Connector="ETH2" TargetModule="+0.1.2HUB" TargetConnector="PLK1" />
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
 <Connection Connector="ETH8" TargetModule="80274418TLS03" TargetConnector="IF3">
    <Cable Type="PowerlinkCable" Length="10" Version="1.0.0.3" />
 </Connection>
```

At the moment im try to use the streamreader too read the file, I'm open for better options

EDIT: its not an XML file, ony the inner part is an XML.

```
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathFile))
                {
                    string line;
                    // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
                    // the file is reached.
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string compare = "<Module Name=\"" + moduleName + "\" Type=\"0AC808.9\"";
         
                        // look for an string 
                        if (line.Contains(compare))
                        {
                            return True;
                        }
                    }
                    return False; // modul not found
                }
            }
```

Comment: To interpret and edit XML files, better use the XML classes in .NET (XmlReader, XmlDocument, XDocument etc.) This ensures that the result will be valid XML

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Basic Queries (LINQ to XML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/basic-queries-linq-to-xml) and [LINQ to XML overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview)

Comment: The following may be helpful: [XElement.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.parse?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of built-in .NET classes to handle reading, writing, and validating XML files without having to parse them manually: [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-7.0), [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-7.0), and [`XPathNavigator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator?view=net-7.0).

In any case, I suggest you use [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-7.0) from your file, and use that to perform any validations, modifications, etc. that you may need to do.

You will be reading your XML file using `XmlReader` and then loading the data from there into your `XmlDocument` which will allow for easy manipulation of the data.

You can then write the changes back to the XML file using `XmlWriter`.

Keep in mind that these classes work with in-memory versions of the XML file.

EDIT: I just realized that `XmlDocument` has helper functions to perform all of these actions directly. For example:

```
var myXmlFile = new XmlDocument();
myXmlFile.Load("myLocalFile.xml");
```

will load the file. The XmlDocument page linked above gives very detailed example on all of the possible actions.

Comment: My problem ist that the File ist not an .xml its an .hw file. the XML reader dos not like it, is there a possibility to "convince" him to open it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

One popular library is the 'System.Xml' namespace, which is part of the .NET framework. This namespace provides a set of classes for reading and writing 'XML documents', including the XmlDocument class, which represents an XML document and allows you to edit its contents.

Another popular library is LINQ to XML, which provides an API for querying and manipulating XML using the LINQ (Language Integrated Query) syntax. You can use the 'XElement' class to represent an XML element, and the 'XDocument' class to represent an XML document.

You can also use a third-party library such as XmlTextEdit that provide more feature and more flexibility when working with XML text in C#.

Here is an example of how you can use the XmlDocument class to edit an XML

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("example.xml");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/books/book");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   XmlElement element = (XmlElement)node;
   element.SetAttribute("author", "John Smith");
}

doc.Save("example.xml");
```